# Count number of occurences in past 14 days of certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column and a id column. I would like to return the number of occurences the the id of each line, in the past 14 days prior to the corresponding date of each line. That means, I would like to return "1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1". How can I do this? Performance is important since the dataframe has a len of 200,000 rows or so. Thanks !

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 |
| 2021-01-08 | 1 |
| 2021-01-28 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is sorted by date, you can use a `GroupBy.rolling` approach:

```
# only required if date is not datetime type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df.assign(count=1)
   .set_index('date')
   .groupby('id')
   .rolling('14d')['count'].sum()
   .sort_index(level='date').reset_index() #optional if order is not important
)
```

output:

```
   id       date  count
0   1 2021-01-01    1.0
1   1 2021-01-04    2.0
2   2 2021-01-05    1.0
3   2 2021-01-06    2.0
4   1 2021-01-07    3.0
5   1 2021-01-08    4.0
6   1 2021-01-28    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the best idea or not, but the code below is what I have come up with:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
newColumn = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  endDate = row["date"]
  startDate = endDate - timedelta(days=14)
  id = row["id"]
  summation = df[(df["date"] >= startDate) & (df["date"] <= endDate) & (df["id"] == id)]["id"].count()
  newColumn.append(summation)
df["check_column"] = newColumn
df
```

##### Output

|  | date | id | check_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 2021-01-28 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

##### Explanation

In this approach, I have used `iterrows` in order to loop over the dataframe's rows. Additionally, I have used `timedelta` in order to subtract 14 days from the date column.

Comment: I tried something very, very similar. However, it is unfortunately way too slow for the size of the dataframe :( Thanks a lot, anyways!

Comment: @pwklein try [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71383601/16343464), tested on 210k rows, and it runs in 44ms

Comment: @pwklein No problem, I highly suggest you use the @mozway `s approach since its execution time would be much lower than mine.